# Simple select query taking too long

Tags: postgresql, select, execution-plan

I have been having a hard time with this query, I have a webpage which is supposed to run this query a dozen of times, and with an execution time up to 40 - 50 seconds per query, you can see how this is becoming quite problematic as the database keeps growing.

Query:

```
select distinct(scanid) 
from misspelled 
where word = ?
```

knowing that the table 'misspelled' can grow up to a dozen million rows, is there any way to make this work ?

Thanks, here are more details:

Query:

```
select distinct(scanid) 
from misspelled 
where word = ?
```

Explain Analyze:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=76018.68..76018.79 rows=11 width=8) (actual time=38359.639..38359.823 rows=1071 loops=1)
  Group Key: scanid
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on misspelled  (cost=1014.12..75918.78 rows=39960 width=8) (actual time=49.946..38319.196 rows=37993 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (word = 'Facebook*'::text)"
        Heap Blocks: exact=28920
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_scanid  (cost=0.00..1004.13 rows=39960 width=0) (actual time=40.541..40.541 rows=37993 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (word = 'Facebook*'::text)
Planning time: 197.561 ms
Execution time: 38360.440 ms
```

Also available at: http://explain.depesz.com/s/7ttn

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE misspelled
(
  word text,
  url text,
  occnum BIGINT,
  proper BOOLEAN,
  scanid BIGINT,
  CONSTRAINT misspelled_scanid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (scanid)
      REFERENCES scans (scanid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT misspelled_word_url_scanid_key UNIQUE (word, url, scanid)
);

CREATE INDEX test_scanid
  ON misspelled
  USING btree
  (word COLLATE pg_catalog."default", scanid);
```

http://pastebin.com/D6jrT2NC

Version 9.4.0

If you need anything else please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: `distinct` is ***not*** a function. Writing `distinct (scanid)` does not make sense.

Comment: The planning time of 200ms seems strange. What kind of computer is that? Does the performance improve after running `vacuum analyze misspelled`? Or even `vacuum full`? You should also upgrade as soon as possible to 9.4.5. There have been a **lot** of bugfixes since 9.4.0

Comment: And you may use an index on `(word, scanid)`

Comment: Computer has an I7-2600K and 16 GB of RAM.
I tried running vacuum analyze and it didn't do anything, I'll try vacuum full and upgrading to 9.4.5 and see if there is any improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have almost 40000 rows where `word='Facebook*'`. I suppose that these rows are somewhat randomly scattered on the whole table. This means that Postgres has to read tens of thousands of random blocks from a disk, which might be slow.

You can try to [cluster rows that have the same word together](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-cluster.html). You can use the command `cluster misspelled using test_scanid;`. This would take some time and block the table until done, so plan accordingly.

Comment: Please note that the order achieved this way will slowly vanish - `CLUSTER` is a one-time operation, subsequent `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statements will not try to put their rows in order.